# show sum result group by date mysqli

Tags: php, date, mysqli, group-by, sum

I have an issue by showing wrong result when I need to show a table with a total price ORDER BY order_date

I have a database with:

```
- order_id
- order_date
- order_price
- order_quantity
```

I tried :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, 
                                 SUM(order_q) * SUM(order_price) as total 
                          FROM o_orders_f 
                          GROUP BY order_id");
```

but this code will sum all results and give me wrong answer

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, 
                                  SUM(order_quantity) * SUM(order_price) as total 
                           FROM o_orders_f 
                           GROUP BY order_id");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $date = $r['order_date'];
   $total = $r['total'];
   echo $total;     
}
```

the result I'm looking for is like this:

```
7 Jul, 2019 - total: ($r['quantity']* $r['price']) = 72933 
8 Jul, 2019 - total: ($r['quantity']* $r['price']) = 453
9 Jul, 2019 - total: ($r['quantity']* $r['price']) = 72
```

Comment: And what is the result you're currently getting?

Comment: 84108114, this means it count all the data

Comment: Can you share some sample-data, preferably in a fiddle like http://sqlfiddle.com/ - then update your query to show what result you are currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 errors in your query:

1. You are grouping by order_id when you should be grouping by `order_date`.
2. When multiplying values on the query, you should `SUM` the result of the operation, but you are summing its factors.

That said, your query should be:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(order_quantity * order_price) as total 
FROM 
    o_orders_f 
GROUP BY 
    order_date
```